# Login com instagram em app Android

Tags: android, oauth2, oauth, instagram-api

Tenho uma duvida de iniciante que esta me causando um certo transtorno. Como logar com uma conta do Instagram e pegar a lista de seguidores e de pessoas que sigo?

Ja vi varias video aulas sobre isso mas nao consigo colocar em pratica no android. Ja li a documentação do OAuth2.0, o tutorial em Instagram developers, etc e nada resolveu. Minhas duvidas sao sobre como colocar isso tudo organizado na aplicação. Sei os conceitos mas nao consigo usar na pratica.

Alguém pode me indicar um tutorial  sobre isso ou enviar um exemplo completo de código para eu entender o funcionamento na pratica? Mas um exemplo basico, ja encontrei diversos cursos onde a pessoa começa com o login e termina misturando com outros assuntos que me deixam ainda mais confuso.

Isso é apenas o inicio do meu projeto de app mas nao tenho como seguir adiante sem isso. Obrigado a quem puder ajudar. Abraço a todos.

Comment: O instagram no passado tinha uma api para isso, mas agora visando segurança login não pode ser feito através de apps terceiros, claro o site sim, mas api do instagram para implementar na sua aplicação como login não tem como...

Comment: Olá Rogers, obrigado por sua resposta. Creio haver um meio pois atualmente temos vários exemplos de apps que utilizam essa funcionalidade.

Comment: Veja a lista de permissões possíveis https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/